# How can I copy a graphical object and change its properties before inserting it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Say I have a simple plot:

```
f = figure;
line = plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]);
```

I can make a copy of the line with `copyobj`, and change some properties:

```
line2 = copyobj(line, line.Parent);
set(line2, 'SomeProp', ...);
```

Is there any way to modify the properties after the copy, but before setting the `.Parent`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that passing a string into `copyobj` trick it into not setting the parent:

```
line2 = copyobj(line, 'tricked you');
assert(isempty(line2.Parent));
set(line2, 'SomeProp', ...);
line2.Parent = line.Parent;
```

I can't find any documentation for why this isn't just an error though